# How to indent 4 spaces for case in switch in javascript mode

Tags: javascript

I'm using default javascript mode and the switch..case look like this:

```
    switch (component) {
    case 'action-message':
        result = actionMessage(response);
        break;

    case 'action-confirmation':
        result = actionConfirmation(response);
        break;

    case 'action-error':
        result = actionError(response);
        break;

    case 'field-error':
        result = fieldError(response);
        break;

    default:
        result = undefined;
        break;
    }
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
    switch (component) {
        case 'action-message':
            result = actionMessage(response);
            break;

        case 'action-confirmation':
            result = actionConfirmation(response);
            break;

        case 'action-error':
            result = actionError(response);
            break;

        case 'field-error':
            result = fieldError(response);
            break;

        default:
            result = undefined;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the variable `js-switch-indent-offset` to 4.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using *js2-mode*, the `js2-indent-switch-body` var should be set at `true`:

`(setq js2-indent-switch-body t)`

Comment: I'm using javascript-mode